# posicionar label en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy realizando una aplicacion, necesito que unos de los label en este caso **cabecera2** quede en la ubicacion rows 3 column 1, no se cual es la razon porque no me queda en esa ubicacion y me queda debajo de **cabecera** les dejo el codigo

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror


# root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('DATOS')
root.geometry('400x200')


# frame
frame = ttk.Frame(root)

# Cabezera1
# ,font='Helvetica 15 bold'
cabecera = ttk.Label(root, text='DATO', background='red')
cabecera.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2)

# Cabezera2
cabecera2 = ttk.Label(root, text='DATO1', background='blue')
cabecera2.grid(column=0, row=3)

# este
este_label = ttk.Label(frame, text='DATO2')
este_label.grid(column=0, row=1)

# norte
norte_label = ttk.Label(frame, text='DATO3')
norte_label.grid(column=0, row=2)

# este entrada
este = tk.StringVar()
este_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=este)
este_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)
este_entry.focus()

# oeste entrada
norte = tk.StringVar()
norte_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=norte)
norte_entry.grid(column=1, row=2)
norte_entry.focus()

# Etiqueta
etiqueta_1 = ttk.Label(frame, text="RESULT", background='red')
etiqueta_1.grid(row=4, column=0)

# result label1
result_1 = ttk.Label(frame, font='Helvetica 11 bold')
result_1.grid(row=4, column=1)

# Etiqueta
etiqueta_2 = ttk.Label(frame, text="RESUTL")
etiqueta_2.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky='W')

# result label2
result_label2 = ttk.Label(frame, font='Helvetica 11 bold')
result_label2.grid(row=5, column=1)

# add padding to the frame and show it
frame.grid(padx=10, pady=10)


#boton 1
convert_button1 = ttk.Button(frame, text='Convertir')
convert_button1.grid(column=2, row=1)


#boton 2
convert_button1 = ttk.Button(frame, text='Convertir')
convert_button1.grid(column=2, row=2)


# start the app
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta la jerarquía de los widgets para colocarlos en la GUI. En tu caso, tienes `'root'`, donde has colocado un frame, y los dos label `'cabecera1'` y `'cabecera2'`, y después tienes el resto de labels que has colocado dentro de `'frame'`, y que son independientes de `'root'`. Es decir, tienes dos zonas `'grid'` donde colocas los widgets, que son totalmente independientes entre sí; una en `'root'`, y otra diferente en `'frame'`.

La forma correcta de solucionarlo es colocar los dos label `'cabecera1'` y `'cabecera2'` dependientes de `'frame'` (igual que el resto de widgets), en lugar de `'root'`.